# NSTableView does not refresh after update

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm stuck with a `NSTable` refresh problem....

I update a DetailViewController table and do the

```
[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

When I then hit the back button the table records are not changed even though I reload the table with a `NSNotification` setting.

Now if I go back and update another record and go back after the first updated record reflects the changes made before.....

After the app is closed and reopened all the changes are reflected so I know it's saving, just not refreshing.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (managedObjectContext == nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [(APLViewController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = context;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
     NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];
    NSError *error1 = nil;
    NSArray *productArray = @[sortDescriptor];
    productArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  initWithArray:[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error1 ]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortAZ = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortZA = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [productArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortAZ, nil]];
    NSArray *desortedArray = [productArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortZA, nil]];
    _products = sortedArray;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Could you show us some code how you do that reloading in ViewController. Why are you need NSNotification here? It sounds like your fetch request is not executing when you returning from DetailViewController to ViewController.

Comment: Thanks Armands, I added the viewWillAppear part